# How can I replace "from urllib2 import Request, urlopen" in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I find code. Below is the code.

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
...
request=Request('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations='+path1+'&sensor=false')
response = urlopen(request)
elevations = response.read()
data = json.loads(elevations)
...
```

So, I tried this code. But in Python3, I can't use urllib2.

Then, How can I use `Reques` and `urlopen` ??

Comment: ah, I got it. from urllib.request import urlopen,Request